# nginx: understanding “=” modifier in location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to add special header for the index.html file following the documentation here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location. I want to provide `X-foo: index` when requested without any path i.e. requested with `/`.

I used “=” modifier and tried with this config first:

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;


        root /tmp/web;
        index index.html;

        location = / {
            add_header X-foo "index";
        }

        location / {
            add_header X-foo "other";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I got `X-foo: other` for both of `/` and `/foo.html`.
If I put a `return 200` inside the first location block, I get `X-foo: index` header but without any content.

Now if I specify `index.html` in the path and specify the config like:

```
location = /index.html {
   add_header X-foo "index";
}
```

I get `X-foo: index` for the `/` request. Seems like on receiving of `/` nginx is rerouting the request internally to `/index.html` again. Is my understanding correct or there is something I am missing while using the “=” modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what Nginx does.

The [`index` module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) internally rewrites the URI from `/` to `/index.html` then restarts the search for a matching `location` to process the request.

The `location` that **finally** processes the request is the one that provides the `add_header` content, **not** the `location` that receives the initial request.